# Assigning each invoice a numeric ID?

Tags: php, sql, api, stripe-payments, webhooks

What would be the best way to give each invoice I generate through Stripe an invoice number? I understand that the system already assigns each invoice with a unique ID but for British accounting I need to figure out a way to have the first invoice i generate be numbered #1, the second #2 and so on.

I've considered maybe storing a count of generated invoices on my site and then subscribing to the webhook that's fired on invoice creation and using that to create some kind of metadata record of an invoice number but i'm not sure this is the most efficient method really.

I'm running a standard kind of LAMP set-up on my VPS and am now quite familiar with the Stripe API although i've never used webhooks before.

Comment: The _accepted answer_ shows good understanding of the question and accommodation for the actual needs as described in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a database table for all your invoices. Then use webhooks to be notified of events and watch for `invoice.created` events. Store the invoice details in your database table, and you can internally use the automatically incremented primary key as your invoice ID, which will be in chronological order.

Cheers,
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.

Comment: Okay wicked, is there a way i can send test webhooks a bunch of times. This is the biggest PHP project i've ever undertaken and I'm having to test after almost every code change to keep myself on track.

Comment: Not in any automated way. You can use the dashboard to send one-off tests. Or you could create code that replicate webhooks for yourself, if need be. Or you could just fake it by storing one set of webhooks data in a string and having the webhooks script act as if that was received from Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

There are invoices and there are transactions. Those two shouldn't be mixed together.

You should store your invoices in your app (HDD, database, whatever) and assign each of them a transaction_id from stripe when it's paid.

Reasons to do that:
- it's more scalable.  Maybe one day your clients would like/have to pay with a check, or wire transfer
- maybe you'll have to change the payment processor in the future
- maybe one client would have to pay two invoices with one transaction 
and so on...

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Adrian. Could you explain what the transaction actually represents? I can find much in the docs.


**Bit more detail for anyone else**
I'm currently retrieving the invoice objects from stripe for a customer and displaying them to the customer in a more traditional invoice layout which they can print and use for their book-keeping and accounting needs, just like any normal business to business exchange.

But with book keeping in the UK we are required to number each invoice we issue, i was wondering what suggestions people had for how to automate and regulate this.

Comment: the transaction is the actual payment. in my opinion, you should make your own invoice system and not rely on stripe's.